# Rewrite of NGINX to Laravel 5 in an online host

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, url-rewriting, laravel-5

I want to know the path of the configuration file for Nginx server in an online host to remove index.php from the URL.

For ex  `http://site/public/index.php/more` should be converted to `http://site/more`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Nginx, the following directive in your site configuration will allow "pretty" URLs:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: This is in the default when you set up homestead.